# Получение имени учетной записи удаленного хоста C#

Tags: c#

Как можно получить имя учетной записи удаленного хоста в локальной сети?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT:");
foreach (DirectoryEntry computers in root.Children)
{
    foreach (DirectoryEntry computer in computers.Children)
    {
        if (computer.Name != "Schema")
        {
             textBox1.Text += computer.Name + "\r\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А можно по ip адресу обратиться к компу и получить имя учетной записи ? Если можно, то каким образом?